# Should I use else when I don't need to?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I know this is a dumb question probably already answered, but I can't find an easy to search for it.  My question is should I be using "else" when I don't need to?  Using VB.NET...

```
Function IsHappy(hasBeer As Boolean)
        If hasBeer = True Then Return "Happy"
        msgbox("I'm sad")
        Return "Sad"
End Function
```

Or...

```
Function IsHappy(hasBeer As Boolean)
    If hasBeer = True Then
        Return "Happy"
    Else
        msgbox("I'm sad")
        Return "Sad"
    End If
End Function
```

These look the same to me, except that the first one is just a bit less code to look, but the second one is a bit clearer though more verbose.  Is there a reason to pick one of these over the other?

Edit: Removed the obvious short cut of just returning hasBeer and made it slightly more complex

To clarify, I'm just trying to figure out if there is a good reason to use an else statement when the IF is going to exit your early if you don't.  Is it just a style choice with no clear preference?

Comment: Why? _Return hasBeer_ and move on.

Comment: You should define all possible code paths. But here you can simply return `hasBeer`

Comment: What about when hasBeer isn't true or false?  Add another else branch to handle this situation.  Well, makes as much sense as adding an `else` after a branch that ends in a return.

Comment: a Boolean per definition is true or false unless you are seriously messing with logic.

Comment: @Steve Well, makes as much sense as adding an `else` after a branch that ends in a return.

Comment: It's just an example... I am not actually coding a beer checker.  I know I can just return the value of hasBeer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Here, I'd use an [*early exit*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18454/33843):

```
Function IsHappy(hasBeer As Boolean) as Boolean
    If hasBeer Then
        Return True
    End If

    ' Complicated logic to determine whether another reason
    ' for being happy can be determined
    ...

    Return False   ' No reason found
End Function
```

Here, I'd use `If` and `Else`:

```
Function IsHappy(hasBeer As Boolean) As Boolean
    If hasBeer Then
        ' Do some side effects
        ...

        Return True
    Else
        ' Do other side effects
        ...

        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

In your example, I'd simply use

```
Function IsHappy(hasBeer As Boolean) As Boolean
    Return hasBeer
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I know your hasBeer flag is just an example - the logic is likely to be much more complex.

I prefer the first option because there is less visual clutter. I might add whitespace before the last line - it makes it very clear that any path that gets this far returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Verbosity is not, in and of itself, a problem.  Performance being equal, clarity almost always trumps clever code in real world applications.